# Facebook App settings to enable email once the user disables it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, python-social-auth, facebook-app-settings

I am using python social auth. I have integrated sign in / sign up with facebook with my website.I have this problem with facebook app settings:
If a user successfully signed in with facebook in my website and then [refer screen shot here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztvs1ove62yy5n1/fb3.png?dl=0] he removes the tick mark on the Email address and save it ,The Email address section is not displayed the next time he opens up the app settings and user will not be able to sign in with facebook.
Is there anyway the user can enable the email address tick mark again in the app settings ?

The only solution i could find was this :

1. User should remove the app and
2. try sign in with facebook in the website again.Where he can see a pop up from facebook with an option to tick the email address and public profile.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask for declined permissions again based on when it is needed. 
From the [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#handling):

> If someone has declined a permission for your app, the login dialog
>   won't let your app re-request the permission unless you pass
>   `auth_type=rerequest` along with your request.

You can find some implementation details of Re-asking for Declined Permissions of [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4#re-asking-declined-permissions).